# Installing CLTK in Jupyter Notebook (Anaconda)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am trying to install CLTK in Jupyter Notebook and then use it to process some latin texts.
Although trying to install this library, I am always getting the following error:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: fasttext, python-Levenshtein
  Building wheel for fasttext (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/xr/qnv284y17_7__833thz7bymw0000gn/T/pip-install-xpoq70mc/fasttext_3720e21e8d4c4d75b80604497dde0fa8/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/xr/qnv284y17_7__833thz7bymw0000gn/T/pip-install-xpoq70mc/fasttext_3720e21e8d4c4d75b80604497dde0fa8/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/xr/qnv284y17_7__833thz7bymw0000gn/T/pip-wheel-apa2byl_
       cwd: /private/var/folders/xr/qnv284y17_7__833thz7bymw0000gn/T/pip-install-xpoq70mc/fasttext_3720e21e8d4c4d75b80604497dde0fa8/
                    ~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  src/fasttext.cc:314:27: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') and 'const int' [-Wsign-compare]
      if (i1 == eosid && i2 == eosid) { // satisfy strict weak ordering
                         ~~ ^  ~~~~~
  src/fasttext.cc:314:12: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') and 'const int' [-Wsign-compare]
      if (i1 == eosid && i2 == eosid) { // satisfy strict weak ordering
          ~~ ^  ~~~~~
  src/fasttext.cc:317:34: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'const int' and 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
      return eosid == i1 || (eosid != i2 && norms[i1] > norms[i2]);
                             ~~~~~ ^  ~~
  src/fasttext.cc:317:18: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'const int' and 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
      return eosid == i1 || (eosid != i2 && norms[i1] > norms[i2]);
             ~~~~~ ^  ~~
  src/fasttext.cc:337:40: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'const size_t' (aka 'const unsigned long') and 'int64_t' (aka 'long long') [-Wsign-compare]
    if (qargs.cutoff > 0 && qargs.cutoff < input->size(0)) {
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  src/fasttext.cc:342:24: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'std::vector<int>::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
      for (auto i = 0; i < idx.size(); i++) {
                       ~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~
  src/fasttext.cc:393:25: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int32_t' (aka 'int') and 'std::vector<int>::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
    for (int32_t w = 0; w < line.size(); w++) {
                        ~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~
  src/fasttext.cc:397:41: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'std::vector<int>::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
        if (c != 0 && w + c >= 0 && w + c < line.size()) {
                                    ~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~
  src/fasttext.cc:411:25: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int32_t' (aka 'int') and 'std::vector<int>::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
    for (int32_t w = 0; w < line.size(); w++) {
                        ~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~
  src/fasttext.cc:415:41: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'std::vector<int>::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
        if (c != 0 && w + c >= 0 && w + c < line.size()) {
                                    ~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~
  src/fasttext.cc:495:27: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int32_t' (aka 'int') and 'std::vector<int>::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
      for (int32_t i = 0; i < line.size(); i++) {
                          ~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~
  src/fasttext.cc:530:25: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int32_t' (aka 'int') and 'std::vector<int>::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
    for (int32_t i = 0; i < ngrams.size(); i++) {
                        ~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  src/fasttext.cc:591:23: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'std::vector<std::pair<float, std::string>>::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') and 'int32_t' (aka 'int') [-Wsign-compare]
        if (heap.size() == k && similarity < heap.front().first) {
            ~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~
  src/fasttext.cc:596:23: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'std::vector<std::pair<float, std::string>>::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') and 'int32_t' (aka 'int') [-Wsign-compare]
        if (heap.size() > k) {
            ~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~
  src/fasttext.cc:696:24: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') and 'int64_t' (aka 'long long') [-Wsign-compare]
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                       ~ ^ ~
  src/fasttext.cc:701:26: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') and 'int64_t' (aka 'long long') [-Wsign-compare]
      for (size_t j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
                         ~ ^ ~~~
  src/fasttext.cc:713:24: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') and 'int64_t' (aka 'long long') [-Wsign-compare]
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                       ~ ^ ~
  src/fasttext.cc:718:26: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') and 'int64_t' (aka 'long long') [-Wsign-compare]
      for (size_t j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
                         ~ ^ ~~~
  src/fasttext.cc:803:25: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int32_t' (aka 'int') and 'std::vector<std::thread>::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
    for (int32_t i = 0; i < threads.size(); i++) {
                        ~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  20 warnings generated.
  x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O3 -pipe -fdebug-prefix-map=${SRC_DIR}=/usr/local/src/conda/${PKG_NAME}-${PKG_VERSION} -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix -flto -Wl,-export_dynamic -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O3 -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem /Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem /Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/include -I/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -I/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -Isrc -I/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c src/utils.cc -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src/utils.o -stdlib=libc++ -DVERSION_INFO="0.9.2" -std=c++14 -fvisibility=hidden
  clang-12: warning: -Wl,-export_dynamic: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
  x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O3 -pipe -fdebug-prefix-map=${SRC_DIR}=/usr/local/src/conda/${PKG_NAME}-${PKG_VERSION} -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix -flto -Wl,-export_dynamic -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O3 -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem /Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem /Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/include -I/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -I/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -Isrc -I/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c src/model.cc -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src/model.o -stdlib=libc++ -DVERSION_INFO="0.9.2" -std=c++14 -fvisibility=hidden
  clang-12: warning: -Wl,-export_dynamic: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
  x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O3 -pipe -fdebug-prefix-map=${SRC_DIR}=/usr/local/src/conda/${PKG_NAME}-${PKG_VERSION} -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix -flto -Wl,-export_dynamic -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O3 -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem /Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem /Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/include -I/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -I/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -Isrc -I/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c src/loss.cc -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src/loss.o -stdlib=libc++ -DVERSION_INFO="0.9.2" -std=c++14 -fvisibility=hidden
  clang-12: warning: -Wl,-export_dynamic: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
  src/loss.cc:83:21: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'std::vector<std::pair<float, int>>::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') and 'int32_t' (aka 'int') [-Wsign-compare]
      if (heap.size() == k && std_log(output[i]) < heap.front().first) {
          ~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~
  src/loss.cc:88:21: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'std::vector<std::pair<float, int>>::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') and 'int32_t' (aka 'int') [-Wsign-compare]
      if (heap.size() > k) {
          ~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~
  src/loss.cc:257:25: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int32_t' (aka 'int') and 'std::vector<int>::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
    for (int32_t i = 0; i < pathToRoot.size(); i++) {
                        ~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  src/loss.cc:282:19: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'std::vector<std::pair<float, int>>::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') and 'int32_t' (aka 'int') [-Wsign-compare]
    if (heap.size() == k && score < heap.front().first) {
        ~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~
  src/loss.cc:289:21: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'std::vector<std::pair<float, int>>::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') and 'int32_t' (aka 'int') [-Wsign-compare]
      if (heap.size() > k) {
          ~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~
  5 warnings generated.
  x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O3 -pipe -fdebug-prefix-map=${SRC_DIR}=/usr/local/src/conda/${PKG_NAME}-${PKG_VERSION} -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix -flto -Wl,-export_dynamic -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O3 -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem /Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem /Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/include -I/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -I/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -Isrc -I/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c src/productquantizer.cc -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src/productquantizer.o -stdlib=libc++ -DVERSION_INFO="0.9.2" -std=c++14 -fvisibility=hidden
  clang-12: warning: -Wl,-export_dynamic: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
  src/productquantizer.cc:246:22: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'std::vector<float>::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
    for (auto i = 0; i < centroids_.size(); i++) {
                     ~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  1 warning generated.
  x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O3 -pipe -fdebug-prefix-map=${SRC_DIR}=/usr/local/src/conda/${PKG_NAME}-${PKG_VERSION} -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix -flto -Wl,-export_dynamic -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O3 -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem /Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem /Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/include -I/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -I/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -Isrc -I/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c src/args.cc -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src/args.o -stdlib=libc++ -DVERSION_INFO="0.9.2" -std=c++14 -fvisibility=hidden
  clang-12: warning: -Wl,-export_dynamic: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
  src/args.cc:120:23: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'std::vector<std::string>::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
    for (int ai = 2; ai < args.size(); ai += 2) {
                     ~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~
  1 warning generated.
  x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O3 -pipe -fdebug-prefix-map=${SRC_DIR}=/usr/local/src/conda/${PKG_NAME}-${PKG_VERSION} -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix -flto -Wl,-export_dynamic -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O3 -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem /Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem /Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/include -I/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -I/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -Isrc -I/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c src/quantmatrix.cc -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src/quantmatrix.o -stdlib=libc++ -DVERSION_INFO="0.9.2" -std=c++14 -fvisibility=hidden
  clang-12: warning: -Wl,-export_dynamic: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
  x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O3 -pipe -fdebug-prefix-map=${SRC_DIR}=/usr/local/src/conda/${PKG_NAME}-${PKG_VERSION} -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix -flto -Wl,-export_dynamic -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O3 -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem /Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem /Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/include -I/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -I/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -Isrc -I/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c src/matrix.cc -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src/matrix.o -stdlib=libc++ -DVERSION_INFO="0.9.2" -std=c++14 -fvisibility=hidden
  clang-12: warning: -Wl,-export_dynamic: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
  x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O3 -pipe -fdebug-prefix-map=${SRC_DIR}=/usr/local/src/conda/${PKG_NAME}-${PKG_VERSION} -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix -flto -Wl,-export_dynamic -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O3 -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem /Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem /Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/include -I/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -I/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -Isrc -I/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c src/meter.cc -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src/meter.o -stdlib=libc++ -DVERSION_INFO="0.9.2" -std=c++14 -fvisibility=hidden
  clang-12: warning: -Wl,-export_dynamic: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
  x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O3 -pipe -fdebug-prefix-map=${SRC_DIR}=/usr/local/src/conda/${PKG_NAME}-${PKG_VERSION} -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix -flto -Wl,-export_dynamic -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O3 -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem /Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem /Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/include -I/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -I/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -Isrc -I/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c src/vector.cc -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src/vector.o -stdlib=libc++ -DVERSION_INFO="0.9.2" -std=c++14 -fvisibility=hidden
  clang-12: warning: -Wl,-export_dynamic: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
  x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O3 -pipe -fdebug-prefix-map=${SRC_DIR}=/usr/local/src/conda/${PKG_NAME}-${PKG_VERSION} -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix -flto -Wl,-export_dynamic -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O3 -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem /Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem /Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/include -I/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -I/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include -Isrc -I/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c src/densematrix.cc -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src/densematrix.o -stdlib=libc++ -DVERSION_INFO="0.9.2" -std=c++14 -fvisibility=hidden
  clang-12: warning: -Wl,-export_dynamic: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
  src/densematrix.cc:48:23: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'unsigned int' [-Wsign-compare]
      for (int i = 0; i < thread; i++) {
                      ~ ^ ~~~~~~
  src/densematrix.cc:51:27: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int32_t' (aka 'int') and 'std::vector<std::thread>::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
      for (int32_t i = 0; i < threads.size(); i++) {
                          ~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  2 warnings generated.
  x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs -Wl,-rpath,/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/lib -L/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/lib -flto -Wl,-export_dynamic -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs -Wl,-rpath,/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/lib -L/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/lib -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs -Wl,-rpath,/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/lib -L/Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/lib -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem /Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem /Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src/dictionary.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src/main.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src/autotune.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src/fasttext.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src/utils.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src/model.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src/loss.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src/productquantizer.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src/args.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src/quantmatrix.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src/matrix.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src/meter.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src/vector.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src/densematrix.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/fasttext_pybind.cpython-38-darwin.so
  ld: warning: -pie being ignored. It is only used when linking a main executable
  ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd' for architecture x86_64
  clang-12: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  error: command 'x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for fasttext
  Running setup.py clean for fasttext
  Building wheel for python-Levenshtein (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/xr/qnv284y17_7__833thz7bymw0000gn/T/pip-install-xpoq70mc/python-levenshtein_4666f8084b754cd0864f1418f860bdc4/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/xr/qnv284y17_7__833thz7bymw0000gn/T/pip-install-xpoq70mc/python-levenshtein_4666f8084b754cd0864f1418f860bdc4/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/xr/qnv284y17_7__833thz7bymw0000gn/T/pip-wheel-iyv1b14u
       cwd: /private/var/folders/xr/qnv284y17_7__833thz7bymw0000gn/T/pip-install-xpoq70mc/python-levenshtein_4666f8084b754cd0864f1418f860bdc4/

  ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-Levenshtein

    Running setup.py install for python-Levenshtein ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/xr/qnv284y17_7__833thz7bymw0000gn/T/pip-install-xpoq70mc/python-levenshtein_4666f8084b754cd0864f1418f860bdc4/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/xr/qnv284y17_7__833thz7bymw0000gn/T/pip-install-xpoq70mc/python-levenshtein_4666f8084b754cd0864f1418f860bdc4/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/xr/qnv284y17_7__833thz7bymw0000gn/T/pip-record-4vren9br/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8/python-Levenshtein
         cwd: /private/var/folders/xr/qnv284y17_7__833thz7bymw0000gn/T/pip-install-xpoq70mc/python-levenshtein_4666f8084b754cd0864f1418f860bdc4/
    Complete output (147 lines):
    /Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/config/__init__.py:28: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: As setuptools moves its configuration towards `pyproject.toml`,
    `setuptools.config.parse_configuration` became deprecated.

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/xr/qnv284y17_7__833thz7bymw0000gn/T/pip-install-xpoq70mc/python-levenshtein_4666f8084b754cd0864f1418f860bdc4/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/xr/qnv284y17_7__833thz7bymw0000gn/T/pip-install-xpoq70mc/python-levenshtein_4666f8084b754cd0864f1418f860bdc4/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/xr/qnv284y17_7__833thz7bymw0000gn/T/pip-record-4vren9br/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/paschalis/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.8/python-Levenshtein Check the logs for full command output.
```

For the installation I used both of the following commands:

```
!pip install cltk
```

and:

```
!{sys.executable} -m pip install cltk
```

and both returned the same error.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Looks like you are experiencing something vaguely similar to [this issue](https://github.com/cltk/cltk/issues/1156). Based on the suggestion there and modern magics commands (see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez)), I'd suggest trying from a cell in your notebook `%pip install python-levenshtein` followed by `%pip install cltk`. Based on comments [here](https://github.com/cltk/cltk/issues/1137#issuecomment-985909776) the issue may be involving Anaconda. For some reason this package seems to work better direct?

Comment: That second issue I lined to before I ran out of space in that comment seems to say not to use Anaconda, and try using venv on your system to make an environment that way. (Rather odd that Anaconda is being recommended against as it is quite popular.)

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/cltk/cltk/issues/841) actually touches on maybe why Anaconda and cltk don't mix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a Mac and am not too familiar with how to setup a built system correctly.

Since it is failing to built `fasttext` and `python-levenstein` though, I would suggest that you try to fulfill these dependencies using `conda`. Additinally, it might be advisable to not do this in the base env of anaconda. There are countless examples here on SO where messing with the base env at some point end up with an unusable state.

So, create a fresh env:

```
conda create -n cltkEnv -c conda-forge fasttext python-Levenshtein
```

Then activate it and try to install `cltk` from pypi:

```
conda activate cltkEnv
pip install cltk
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @FlyingTeller! Your examples almost solved the problem. Using your lines of code I could install successfully cltk, but I couldn't use in the Jupyter Notebook. Coming back to this problem several weeks after this question, I realised that cltk requires specific Python versions [(3.7, 3.8, 3.9)](https://docs.cltk.org/en/latest/installation.html). For future users of cltk in Jupyter Notebook this line may be useful: `conda create -n cltkEnv -c conda-forge fasttext python-Levenshtein python=3.9`